# Integration Build column is not being updated after a TFS build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs-2015

I have created a web TFS build like the image below.

[image]

After I have successfully build my application, the Integration Build column is not being updated and the changesets are not being populated in the email notification.

I'm using TFS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

It's not be updated in Integrated in Build field in TFS 2015 Server with vNext build, only XAML build number will be updated in this field. This has been a uservoice for the  vNext build.

> **vNext builds should update work items with Integration Build field value**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12836916-vnext-builds-should-update-work-items-with-integra

As a workaround you could add a custom build task to implement it yourself: [Build association with work Items in vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/09/build-association-with-work-items-in-vnext/)

And for the changesets are not being populated in the email notification. There's also a uservoice. The changeset data and the associated work items don't seem to be exposed to default *BuildCompletedEvent.xsl*. For more info you could take a look at my answer in this question: [TFS 2017 Build Notifications do not include "Associated Changesets" area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988376/tfs-2017-build-notifications-do-not-include-associated-changesets-area/42996395#42996395)